# Jupyter notebook上でRパッケージが読み込めない

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, bioinformatics

プログラミング初心者です。
minicondaを経由してJupyter notebook上でRを使った解析を行おうとしています。
Rのカーネルの追加までは上手くいったのですが、Rパッケージを読み込もうとすると下記のようなエラーが出ます。
何が原因でしょうか？

OSはmacOS10.15.2を使っています。
pyenv1.2.15を使ってminiconda3-4.3.30を導入しています。

```
library(DESeq2)

Loading required package: S4Vectors
Loading required package: stats4
Loading required package: BiocGenerics
Loading required package: parallel

Attaching package: ‘BiocGenerics’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:parallel’:

    clusterApply, clusterApplyLB, clusterCall, clusterEvalQ,
    clusterExport, clusterMap, parApply, parCapply, parLapply,
    parLapplyLB, parRapply, parSapply, parSapplyLB

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    IQR, mad, sd, var, xtabs

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    anyDuplicated, append, as.data.frame, basename, cbind, colnames,
    dirname, do.call, duplicated, eval, evalq, Filter, Find, get, grep,
    grepl, intersect, is.unsorted, lapply, Map, mapply, match, mget,
    order, paste, pmax, pmax.int, pmin, pmin.int, Position, rank,
    rbind, Reduce, rownames, sapply, setdiff, sort, table, tapply,
    union, unique, unsplit, which, which.max, which.min


Attaching package: ‘S4Vectors’

The following object is masked from ‘package:base’:

    expand.grid

Loading required package: IRanges
Loading required package: GenomicRanges
Loading required package: GenomeInfoDb
Loading required package: SummarizedExperiment
Loading required package: Biobase
Welcome to Bioconductor

    Vignettes contain introductory material; view with
    'browseVignettes()'. To cite Bioconductor, see
    'citation("Biobase")', and for packages 'citation("pkgname")'.

Loading required package: DelayedArray
Loading required package: matrixStats

Attaching package: ‘matrixStats’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:Biobase’:

    anyMissing, rowMedians

Loading required package: BiocParallel

Attaching package: ‘DelayedArray’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:matrixStats’:

    colMaxs, colMins, colRanges, rowMaxs, rowMins, rowRanges

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    aperm, apply, rowsum

Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'ggplot2':
  method         from 
  [.quosures     rlang
  c.quosures     rlang
  print.quosures rlang
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘DESeq2’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
  共有ライブラリ '/Users/naga/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/py2_bio/lib/R/library/DESeq2/libs/DESeq2.dylib' を読み込めません: 
  dlopen(/Users/naga/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/py2_bio/lib/R/library/DESeq2/libs/DESeq2.dylib, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libopenblasp-r0.3.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/naga/.pyenv/versions/miniconda3-4.3.30/envs/py2_bio/lib/R/library/DESeq2/libs/DESeq2.dylib
  Reason: image not found 
Traceback:

1. library(DESeq2)
2. tryCatch({
 .     attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc
 .     ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
 .     env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps, exclude, include.only)
 . }, error = function(e) {
 .     P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e))) 
 .         paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])
 .     else ""
 .     msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s", 
 .         sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))
 .     if (logical.return) 
 .         message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)
 .     else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
 . })
3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5. value[[3L]](cond)
6. stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
```

Comment: エラーメッセージから察するに、OpenBLAS の shared library(libopenblasp-r0.3.7.dylib)が見つからない様です。[この回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50634728)が参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: metropolisさん。確認したところ、環境中にopenblasが導入されていませんでした。改めて導入したところ無事にRパッケージを読み込めるようになりました。本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

エラーメッセージから察するに、OpenBLAS の shared library (libopenblasp-r0.3.7.dylib) が見つからない様です。[この回答](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50634728) が参考になるかもしれません。

---

*この投稿は [@metropolis さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/62132/jupyter-notebook%e4%b8%8a%e3%81%a7r%e3%83%91%e3%83%83%e3%82%b1%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b8%e3%81%8c%e8%aa%ad%e3%81%bf%e8%be%bc%e3%82%81%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment67850_62132) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*